# How are TRUE/FALSE booleans acceptable in lambda calculus?

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

I'm working my way through an introduction to lambda calculus, and it seems to start from the premise that `TRUE` and `FALSE` (as well as everything else) can be encoded as functions. From this, they define these two functions as:

\begin{align}
T & = \lambda a b.a\\
F & = \lambda a b.b
\end{align}

Now, I'm not a genius, but it seems like this looks less like 'booleans' and more like 'first' and 'second' (or left and right, if looking at the equation).

Is this just an agreed-upon convention or how is that allowed? For example, what if I had a function that passed the value of `0` or `False` (or low-voltage or whatever represents zero in the physical world), some examples being:

\begin{align}
& False=0 \\
& True=1 \\
& T(False)(False) \\
& T(0)(0) \\
& T(50)(12) 
\end{align}

Or even passing more than two values to the function, how could one tell where it is True or False?

$$T(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)$$

Maybe I'm missing the boat, but basically I'm curious why what seems to me like such an arbitrary definition of booleans would be allowed in lambda calculus, other than as a convenience where nothing else exists.

Comment: It is just a convention.

Comment: Your example is far from clear as the usual representation of numerals like $0$ and $1$ are not the same as the representation of true and false.

Comment: I would say this is more than just a convention (although other conventions are possible). The canonical use of true and false in a functional programming language is in if-then-else expressions. The standard definitions of true and false that you cite give if-then-else expressions a very simple and natural semantics: "if $c$ then $x$ else $y$" just means $c\,x\,y$.

Comment: @RobArthan I see, so basically it's a "boolean-for-conditional" definition, if that makes sense?

Comment: Yes that makes some kind of sense.The representations of the logical operators follow from this line of thinking: something that I don't think is made clear in the answers to the relevant question that @JohnDouma has  pointed you to.

Comment: This could be seen as a special case of a general way to encode so-called "algebraic data types" (as used commonly in languages such as OCaml and Haskell) into lambda calculus: for example, for the list type, `cons x (cons y nil)` gets encoded as $\lambda a b.a~x~(a~y~b)$; for the natural type (in unary) with constructors `S` (successor) and `O` (zero), $3 = S (S (S O))$ gets encoded as $\lambda a b.a~(a~(a b))$; for the `option` or `Maybe` type with constructors `Some` and `None`, `Some x` gets encoded as $\lambda a b.a~x$ and `None` gets encoded as $\lambda a b.b$; etc.

Comment: Quoting from my answer at one of the linked questions: “What does it mean for something to be true or false?  In this context we are not concerned with abstract truth or falsity.  We just want something that behaves in a  certain way:  We want true and false to be different, and distinguishable, and we want to have some sort of if-then-else construction so that $\mathbf{if}\; b\; \mathbf{then}\; p \;\mathbf{else}\; q$ evaluates to $p$ when $b$ is true, and to $q$ when $b$ is false.  There is nothing more to it than that.”